# Can elasticnet ever select a different set of predictors than LASSO for a given lambda?

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

Since ridge regression can never penalize coefficients to zero, can elasticnet ever select a different set of predictors than LASSO for a given lambda?

Comment: What procedure would you use to select predictors from a ridge regression? How exactly do you define your $\lambda$? (There are several conventions and they lead to different meanings of "same lambda.") What specifically do you mean by "elasticnet"?  Ordinarily it includes both LASSO and RR as extreme cases, with everything else a compromise determined by a parameter $\alpha,$, but it's not often performed by tuning $\alpha.$ How do you want us to deal with the fact that most methods to select predictors are based on *random* cross-validation and thereby can have different results in each run?